# Smaller QPolygon in PyQt than 1 not drawing

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

So im trying to use the drawPolygon() function to draw some shapes in a plot. After a lot of trouble I tried painting this two polygons, the first one does not work and the second one yes:

```
points1 = QPolygon([
                    QPoint(0,0),
                    QPoint(0,0.5),
                    QPoint(0.5,0.5),
                    QPoint(0.5,0)])
points2 = QPolygon([
                    QPoint(0,0),
                    QPoint(0,1),
                    QPoint(1,1),
                    QPoint(1,0)])
p.drawPolygon(points1)
#p.drawPolygon(points2)
p.end()
```

Is something with the drawPolygon function that cant draw a smaller polygon than 1 unit?

I tried to draw a polygon with Qpolygon function. I came up with the problem of not being able to draw a smaller polygon than 1 unit

Comment: How do you expect less than one pixel to appear on a screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QPolygon` and `QPoint` have integer precision

So `QPoint(0, 0.5)` is actually `QPoint(0, 0)`, and your polygon results in 4 congruent points

What should be used are their floating-point versions: `QPolygonF` and `QPointF`

For reference: [Qpoint](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QPoint.html), [QPolygon](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtGui/QPolygon.html), [QPointF](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QPointF.html), [QPolygonF](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtGui/QPolygonF.html)